# C# - Is it possible to send TCP IP Packet to my own external IP for server testing?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

)

I am making a simple server application to send messages to all clients that connected at a certain time. Basically, I start a server, which grabs its internal IP and port and listens. Then on clients, they connect to my routers external IP and port, and send a tcp packet. The problem is this, my client application is never able to successfully send a packet out. It times out.

Here is the code for the server:

```
...
        try
        {
            server_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(192.168.0.xxx), 5000);
            server_listener.Start();
            isRunning = true;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] The server is now listening for all clients!", DateTime.Now);
            Listen();
        }

...



    void Listen()  // Listen to incoming connections.
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = server_listener.AcceptTcpClient();  // Accept incoming connection.

            (new Thread(() => SetupAndListen(tcpClient))).Start(); //handle in a new thread
        }
    }
```

And Client:

```
    //attempt to connect once...
    string textToSend = "CA";

    try
    {
        //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(EXTERNAL_SERVER_IP, 5000);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);


        //---and see if connected---
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        //---read back the text---
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        Debug.Log("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
        client.Close();
    }
    catch { }
```

The server runs fine, no errors, and appears to be listening properly from what I see in the debugger, but none of my clients work. Moreover, if `EXTERNAL_SERVER_IP` is changed to `localhost`, or `192.168.0.xxx` it does infact work. Any thoughts as to what is going on?

Just to note, the port 5000 has indeed been forwarded.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall/network routing issue and not a coding issue if you can use your local IP address to connect successfully. Your modem/router/whatever you're using to connect to the internet is not configured to allow traffic from your external IP address the computer running the server program. You might have better luck asking http://serverfault.com/ for help in configuring your network to do what you're trying.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to send a packet to your server from inside your network, by using your external IP? This will not work with many SoHo routers. The router feature you are asking for is called NAT Loopback.

Comment: Interesting... So reasonably there is no way to test this internally. I have to test on other hosts?

Comment: How could you possibly test whether accessing your server from the outside works correctly from any place other than the outside? The router's NAT functionality on packets inbound from the Internet is a critical piece of how that works.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's possible to test if the router supports NAT Loopback, which emulates this exactly as if you were originating from the outside.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic That is simply not true. It does not emulate it exactly, it does something totally different. NAT loopback is a form of dual NAT. Normal port mapping is not. Think about it from the point of view of the server -- with loopback NAT, both the source and destination IP addresses are translated while with regular port mapping, only the source IP is changed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz For the purpose of this requirement, it will let him do what he wants.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic No, it will not. What's worse, it will *appear* to, making him think it does. Again, loopback NAT is totally different from normal port mapping, and testing one does *not* test the other. Loopback NAT is not some tiny extra thing that makes port mapping work from the inside -- it's something totally different that often gets enabled with the same switch as port mapping.

Comment: So are you all saying I should look and see if my router supports loopback? or is @DavidSchwartz suggesting something different?

Comment: @DevDevDev101010 It depends which of two things you are trying to do. Are you trying to have this work from the inside under normal conditions? Or are you trying to test whether it will work from the outside? If the former, loopback NAT will help. If the latter, loopback NAT will make things worse by providing a way to make things work from the inside that will not work from the outside rendering your test useless.

Comment: Both. I am not guaranteed my clients will be internal or external to my server.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sure, and if it's set up correctly, then it will correctly _appear_ to work just like it would _appear_ to work from the outside. For the purpose of his requirement, that would be fine.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic This is like suggesting that we can test a UPS by adding another source of AC power. If it works with an extra source of AC power, it will work on the UPS. Sure, but you're not testing the UPS. To test a UPS, you need to make sure the UPS is the *only* way it can work. Adding another way it can work makes it *harder* to test the way you wanted to test.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sure - but in order to support both external clients connecting to his external IP address, and internal clients connecting to his external IP address, like I myself have done for many years with iptables, then setting up NAT Loopback will let him do that.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic Agreed, but it does not help test whether the connection is reachable from the outside. Loopback NAT could work while port mapping could fail. They are two very different forms of NAT that just happen to often be enabled with the same switch for convenience, but testing one does not in any way test the other.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah, I agree with you now - I didn't realise you were arguing against the testability of it. Yes, in that case you would have to actually test it from the outside. But if you want to actually support it, then you can implement NAT Loopback in your router as well as regular port mapping to have both systems work regardless of if you are inside or outside, but to test, you need to test from both internal and external network segments.

Comment: So is there a difference in answers if instead I'd like to *support* it rather than *test* it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is just saying that if you want to know if external clients can connect to your server, then you need to become an external client and try to connect. That's because packets don't take the same path in NAT Loopback as they do in port mapping, so just because it works via NAT Loopback doesn't mean it will work in port mapping. You can't "test" actual external connections from the inside. You can only test NAT Loopback, which pretends to function like external port mapping.

Comment: If you want to make connections to your server using your external IP address, but originating from both inside and outside of your network segment, then look to see if your router supports NAT Loopback, and if it doesn't, buy one that does.

Comment: Re-reading the whole comment section, I can see there was a misunderstanding between what you were asking and what @DavidSchwartz was saying. You were asking about "testing" (connecting to) your server internally using your external IP address, which I said is not possible without NAT Loopback. I think he thought you wanted to test actual external connections from the inside, which lead to the discussion. As I said, if you want to connect to your server from the inside, find a router that supports NAT Loopback, or, simply test everything from the outside instead.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can't use loopback NAT to test if portforwarding is working because they're two completely different things. One can work even if the other does not. Loopback NAT is not just port forwarding extended to internal connections, it's a completely different thing -- port forwarding is destination NAT, loopback NAT is dual NAT. They are different technologically, they are different in where and how they process the packet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, I am aware. As I previously mentioned, it did not sound like he was ever asking how to test if external connections are working by only testing internally, hence why we sparked off on a debate - we were talking about different things. He was asking how to be able to connect to his server internally, while specifying his external IP in his code. When he said "So reasonably there is no way to test this internally", he was talking about testing his server code, not testing the connection. To test his server internally using the external IP, he needs to implement Loopback NAT.

Comment: For the record, I entirely agree with your point, but you were not answering his question. When I said it's exactly the same, I was talking about from the point of view from his server application, because he was talking about testing his server application, not the connections themselves. When I said Loopback NAT would fix his issue, it's because it would. His issue was "how do I connect to my server internally using my external IP". It wasn't "how to I test external connections internally", which as I've already agreed, is a completely different thing. In the latter case, you are correct.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic You still don't understand my point. It's *not* exactly the same from the point of view of the server application. In one case, the packets inbound to the server application have the destination address NATted and in the other they don't. The different forms of NAT result in different looking packets at the application. As a silly example, consider if the server is missing a default route. There are many other ways one can work and the other not, even in the configuration of the server. They really are completely different things.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's nothing more than a silly example. It's difficult to be missing a default route unless your network startup script is broken or router is not giving out information it should be, in which case you have a bigger problem. I understand you are being pedantic, and you are correct - the packets are not identical. One does SNAT, the other DNAT. For the purpose of his question, it's extremely likely that the server application will perform fine using Loopback NAT, which was my answer, and I'll leave it at that.